# ActiveX FSO (FileSystemObject) in Windows8 | Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, activex, internet-explorer-10, fso

Does anyone knows if the activex filesystemobject is blocked or doesn't work in the new windows8/ie10?

Sample code: (javascript)

```
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); //error
d = fso.GetDrive(fso.GetDriveName(fso.GetAbsolutePathName("c:\")));
```

Comment: the error may be the second line: you need to escape the backslash "c:\\"

Answer (score 0):

> the error may be the second line: you need to escape the backslash "c:\"